# XNA beginner - can't display cannon in 2D tutorial

Tags: xna, 2d

I taking my first steps with XNA. I'm building the old 2D tutorial that used to be posted on the XNA website. I got to the part where I display the cannon, but its not showing. Can someone please take a look and say what is wrong. The background texture is displaying fine.

Main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace XNA2DTutorial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D backgroundTexture;
        Rectangle viewportRect;
        GameObject cannon;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites\\background");

            cannon = new GameObject(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites\\cannon"));
            cannon.position = new Vector2(120, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - 80);

            viewportRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, 
                graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
#if !xbox
            KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                cannon.rotation -= 0.1f;
            }
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                cannon.rotation += 0.1f;
            }
#endif
            cannon.rotation = MathHelper.Clamp(cannon.rotation, -MathHelper.PiOver2, 0);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
            spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, viewportRect, Color.White);

            spriteBatch.Draw(cannon.sprite, 
                cannon.position, 
                null, 
                Color.White, 
                cannon.rotation, 
                cannon.center, 
                1.0f, 
                SpriteEffects.None, 
                0);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Game object class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace XNA2DTutorial
{
    public class GameObject
    {
        #region Attributes
        public Texture2D sprite;
        public Vector2 position;
        public float rotation;
        public Vector2 center;
        #endregion Attributes

        #region Constructors
        public GameObject(Texture2D loadedTexture)
        {
            rotation = 0.0f;
            position = Vector2.Zero;
            sprite = loadedTexture;
            center = new Vector2(sprite.Width / 2, sprite.Height / 2);
        }
        #endregion Constructors

        #region Methods
        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your `spriteBatch.Begin` call.

You're passing `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` and since both of your `layerDepths` are equal to 0, I'd guess that the order would get mixed up when the sprites get drawn on the `spriteBatch.End` call, therefore drawing the background on top of the cannon.

Try passing `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` instead. This will draw the sprites immediately when you call `spriteBatch.Draw` and should draw them in the proper order. Works for me at least.

Comment: You should use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` (the default) in XNA 4.0 unless you are doing "tricky things" ([reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritesortmode-immediate-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)).

Comment: @Andrew Russell: Ahhh I knew `BackToFront` had to change but I didn't know to what... I searched a little bit in the hope of finding an article explaining such things but couldn't find any. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Both worked but I'll stick with Deferred. Thanks.